# Using NServiceBus how can I process multiple messages as a batch?

Tags: nservicebus

We currently have an process that involves sending a third-party an xml file containing changes that have occurred within our system.

We are moving to use NServiceBus and the changes are modelled as individual commands sent to an endpoint.

We do not want to send these changes as individual files; instead we want to batch receive a number of commands, concatenating this information into a single file.

How might one go about batching multiple commands into a single export file?

Comment: Why do you want to batch receive a number of commands? Do they form a single atomic unit and should all be either committed or rolled back together?

Comment: Are you using the commands to transfer a file across the wire?  So file -> commands -> file?

Comment: Pretty much; but we will be mapping the commands into an xml format defined by our client.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Sagas?  Sagas allow you to model long-running business processes.  So if a file has multiple parts, the Saga could begin when it gets the first part, and complete when it has all the parts it needs.

http://cdn.nservicebus.com/sagas.aspx

Comment: I have attempted to solve this using a Saga. If I submit messages one at a time then it works.  But under load it has concurrency issues that I am unable to resolve.  Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8664762

Comment: Should your batch identifier be hard coded to use the same Guid/Id always, or am I misunderstanding that bit?

Comment: I don't know what else to use as there is no natural identifier that groups commands as a batch; nor is there a different type of command that is used to start the process.  Instead we just want to process commands in a batch of say 100 at a time.  Ideally we would only have a single saga open at any one time.

Comment: I misunderstood--I thought the parts were all related, and needed to be reassembled when all the parts (of a specific collection) were received.  A saga may still be a good choice, as it gets persisted and is thus durable.  But to be honest I'm not sure how to handle concurrency.  Can you do the batching on the sender side, or assign an id that allows you to correlate the messages together in the saga?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the commands in using Bus.Send(IMessage[]messages).  Note it takes an array and the messages will be packed into one queue message over the wire.  On the receiving side, the handler will be invoked once per message.  In your handler you should be able to just keep appending to your file.  In the handler you could place logic to determine when to "roll" the file if necessary.

Comment: note that this batching feature is obsolete and will be removed in future versions of NSB

Comment: Also we do not have the ability to batch messages up during send.  Instead we only want to batch receive.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind removing it?